# Ionic 2: Pipe to filter async list by name property

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2, pipes-filters

**Q) What is wrong with my syntax/code below?**

I want to filter my list of items by the name property.  I've tried with the code below, but am getting the error:

*Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined*

**Note**: query is defined as an empty string on page load i.e.

```
var query = "";
```

My template:

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="#item of (items | clientNameFilter:query)">
    <img [src]="getItemImage(item)" (click)="editItem(item)"/>
    <ion-card-content (click)="editItem(item)">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.address.name}}</p>
      <p>{{item.address.addressLine1}}</p>
      <p>{{item.address.town}}</p>
      <p>{{item.address.postcode}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

My filter:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
import {Client} from '../interfaces/client';

@Pipe({
  name: 'clientNameFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class ClientNameFilterPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(query: string, clients: Client[]) {
    return clients.filter(client => 
        client.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print `clients` and `client.name` to see when they are `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters aren't in the right order and the second parameter must be an array:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'clientNameFilter'
})
export class ClientNameFilterPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(clients: Client[], params: string[]) {
    let query = params[0];
    return clients.filter(client => 
        client.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1
    );
  }
}
```

The first parameter is the value / list you want the pipe to be applied on and the second one your parameter(s).

See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/PipeTransform-interface.html

Comment: You again! Thanks for your response.  It seems my collection is undefined:  Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.  It's worth noting that the list is an http observable call.

Comment: Oh! So you need to add the async pipe before: `<ion-card *ngFor="#item of (items | async | clientNameFilter:query)">` and check that the clients parameter isn't null. If it's not the case, return null directly...

Comment: hmmm, that just caused the list never to display.  Wrapping the template with:   <div *ngIf="items && items.length > 0">....</div>
seems to work though.  That seem ok?

Comment: You mean `items` is an observable? If not remove `async` but keep the test on null...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working version (for contacts):

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'contactNameFilter'
})
export class ContactNameFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(contacts: Array<any>, searchTerm: string) : Array<any> {
    if (contacts == null) {
      return [];
    }
    if (searchTerm == null) {
      return contacts;
    }
    return contacts.filter( contact => {
      return `${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}`.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let contact of (contacts | async | contactNameFilter:searchTerm)">
```